# Java Swing JComboBox select only available item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` with only one item. When I populate this item to the Box I immediately select it with `combobox.setSelectedItem(item)`. But unfortunately I get -1 / null when I read the item with `combobox.getSelectedIndex(0)` or `combobox.getSelectedItem(item)`.

Sure I know which Item is in the box but I don't want to add a statement to react to that case.

Can you tell me how I can read the lone Item in the combobox?

Comment: Sorry somehow I cant say hello in the main text... So hey folks :D

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Your answer was already correct :D. So I won't post any code if you do not insist regards j0chn

Comment: *"Sorry somehow I cant say hello in the main text..."* This is a technical Q&A site, not a social network. Salutations here are merely noise. Don't include them in questions or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

`combobox.setSelectedItem(item)` takes `item` as an `Object` and checks it among the items. Since c`ombobox.getSelecedIndex` returns -1, we already know that there is no selection, therefore your selection was unsuccessful.

**Reason**

You passed an object to `setSelectedItem`, but that `Object` was not found among the items. It is easily possible that your `Object` is a `String` and you are passing a similar `String` as a parameter, but the parameter you are passing is not the same `String`, bug similar.

**Behavior test**

```
String foo = "bar";
boolean theSame = (foo == "bar"); //false
boolean similar = foo.equals("bar"); //true
```

**Solution**

Use the same `Object` when you call `setSelectedItem` instead of a similar `Object`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your replay. That was the mistake.When I selected it via Constant it works. Thank you